# Connect to an SSH server using Paramiko with a SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, socks

I need to connect to a server via SSH and run some commands, and would like to script the commands using Python. I have tried using Paramiko, but this is difficult because (I think) the ProxyCommand I need to use does not use `ssh` but `nc`.

Given the following SSH config for `myserver`, how can I create a connection this server using Paramiko?

```
Host myserver
  HostName     myserver.domain.tld
  Port         2222
  ForwardAgent yes
  User         myusername
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myprivatekey
  ProxyCommand nc -x socks-proxy.intranet.domain.tld:1085 -X 5 %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Ultimately, this script will be executed on RunDeck, so ideally does not need to rely on OS functions.

I have looked at previous questions but none of them seem to cover my specific use case. This is as far as I have got:

```
# using PySocks
import paramiko 
import socks
sock = socks.socksocket()
sock.set_proxy(
 proxy_type=socks.SOCKS5,
 addr='socks-proxy.intranet.domain.tld',
 port=1085
)
sock.connect(('myserver.domain.tld', 2222))
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/myusername/.ssh/myprivatekey')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('myserver.domain.tld', port=2222, sock=sock, pkey=private_key)
```

The error message I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/image-deleter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 406, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/image-deleter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 660, in start_client
    raise e
  File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/image-deleter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2055, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/image-deleter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 459, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
  File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/image-deleter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 303, in read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

Comment: What have you tried? What error have you got?

Comment: @slackmart question updated

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/955), it doesn't sound like this is possible, unless some new developments have been made since that issue was created.

You could use shell commands to do your SSHing, but this will require Putty to be installed on Windows machines. Here is some code that I have used in the past using this method. It doesn't create the SOCKS proxy, but you should be able to easily modify the shell commands to run under the appropriate SOCKS proxy.

```
import subprocess
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path

serverlist = ['some_server_name' = [
    'ssh-username' = '',
    'host' = '',
    'ssh-password' = '',
]]

def run(server, command, shell=True, outside_ssh='', verbose=False):
    """Determines the best method for running an SSH command, and then runs it, returning the ouput as a string.
    If anything is outputted to stderr, an error is raised. It outside_ssh is provided, it'll be added onto the right-side of the generated command."""

    command = command.replace('"', '\\"')

    if "localhost" in servers_get(server, "host") or "127.0.0.1" in servers_get(server, "host"):
        if verbose:
            print("executing:", command)
        stdout_fh = io.StringIO()
        stderr_fh = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stderr(stderr_fh):
            with redirect_stdout(stdout_fh):
                subprocess.run(command, shell=shell)
        error_msg = stderr_fh.getvalue()
        error_msg = error_msg.replace("stdin: is not a tty", "")
        error_msg = error_msg.replace("Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.", "")
        error_msg = error_msg.strip()
        if error_msg:
            raise SSHError(error_msg)
        return stdout_fh.getvalue()

    s = servers_get(server)
    s_user = s["ssh-username"]
    s_host = s["host"]
    s_passwd = s["ssh-password"]

    if os.name == "nt":
        if command:
            cmd = 'plink -ssh {s_user}@{s_host} -pw {s_passwd} "{command}" {outside_ssh}'.format(**locals())
        else:
            cmd = 'putty -ssh {s_user}@{s_host} -pw {s_passwd} {outside_ssh}'.format(**locals())

        ssh_config = Path("~") / ".ssh" / "config"
        ssh_config = ssh_config.expanduser()
        if ssh_config.is_file() and server in ssh_config.read_text():

            #check if we have to use putty or if we already have ssh keys configured
            #Putty opens up in a new window which is annoying, so if ssh keys are already installed we use those,
            #otherwise, we use putty so that we can pass in the password on the command line
            cmd2 = "ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=1 {server} exit".format(**locals())
            try:
                subprocess.check_output(cmd2) #this will fail if ssh keys are not setup
                cmd = 'ssh {server} "{command}"'.format(**locals())
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                pass
    else:
        cmd = 'sshpass -p "{s_passwd}" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {s_user}@{s_host} "{command}" {outside_ssh}'.format(**locals())

    try:
        try:
            if verbose:
                print("executing:", cmd)
            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        except (FileNotFoundError, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            #if putty is not installed (windows) or if sshpass does not work (Linux), run the normal ssh command and the user will have to type in the password on the command line
            cmd = 'ssh {s_user}@{s_host} "{command}" {outside_ssh}'.format(**locals())
            if verbose:
                print("nevermind, that command failed. Executing", cmd)
            print("use the password {s_passwd} when prompted".format(**locals()))

            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        if proc.stderr:
            ssh_error_msg = b"\n".join(proc.stderr.readlines()).decode("utf-8")
            ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.replace("stdin: is not a tty", "")
            ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.replace("Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.", "")
            ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.strip()
            if ssh_error_msg:
                print()
                print("-"*79)
                print("recieved an error when running the command")
                print(cmd)
                print("-"*79)
                print()
                raise SSHError(ssh_error_msg)
        raise

    if proc.stderr:
        ssh_error_msg = b"\n".join(proc.stderr.readlines()).decode("utf-8")
        ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.replace("stdin: is not a tty", "")
        ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.replace("Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.", "")
        ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.replace("mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.", "")
        ssh_error_msg = re.sub(r"Warning: Permanently added '[^']+' \(ECDSA\) to the list of known hosts.", "", ssh_error_msg)
        # Maybe we should just make any error message starting with "Warning:..." be ignored.
        ssh_error_msg = ssh_error_msg.strip()
        if ssh_error_msg:
            print()
            print("-"*79)
            print("recieved an error when running the command")
            print(cmd)
            print("-"*79)
            print()
            raise SSHError(ssh_error_msg)

    return b"".join(proc.stdout.readlines()).decode("utf-8")

def servers_get(server, lookup=None, deprecated=True):
    """ returns a dictionary of info about a server entry,
    or looks up a specific item in this dictionary if lookup is specified.
    returns None if the server entry does not exist."""
    global serverlist

    if server not in serverlist:
        return
    if lookup:
        return serverlist[server].get(lookup)
    return serverlist[server]

class MyBaseException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, title, message=None):
        """pass in either a title and an error message, or just an error message"""
        if message and title:
            self.title = title
            self.message = self.msg = message
            super(OWException, self).__init__("\n"+"-"*80+"\n"+title+": "+self.message)
        else:
            self.message = self.msg = title
            super(OWException, self).__init__(title)

class SSHError(MyBaseException):
    """ Raised when an SSH command returns a non-zero exit status.
    One of the subprocess error could still be raised if the command fails for some other reason """
    def __init__(self, title, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SSHError, self).__init__(title, message, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title = title
        if not message:
            message = title
        self.message = self.msg = message
```